# Динамический запрос SQL с учетом фильтров

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, postgresql, запрос

подскажите можно ли как то создать динамический SQL запрос, что я имею ввиду? Вот у меня в клиенте есть условных 6 фильтров, которые пользователь может выбирать, а может и не выбирать, если ли способ фильтровать выводимые пользователю данные только с учетом выбранных им фильтров, при этом, не создавать кучу условий в программном коде, учитывая каждый возможный случай.

Привожу пример, если было бы два фильтра user_type и document_type.
Тогда в коде я бы написал 4 условия.

1. Если не выбран ни один из фильтров, то есть вывожу все данные из таблицы.
2. Если выбран только определенный user_type
3. Если выбран только определенный document_type
4. Если выбраны оба фильтра

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [mybatis](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/).

Он позволяет создавать динамические SQL запросы и мапить результат в объекты (это не полноценный ORM, а продвинутый маппер). Также он поддерживает скриптовые движки шаблонов, в частности [velocity](http://mybatis.org/velocity-scripting/).

Если использовать mybatis вместе со стандартным плагином к velocity, то запрос будет выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyEntity
#where()
  #if($_parameter.user_type)
    @{user_type} = user_type
  #end
  #if($_parameter.document_type)
    AND @{document_type} = document_type
  #end
#end
```

При вызове метода мапера mybatis сгенерирует запрос включая части условия в зависимости от того, какие параметры заданы. Если ничего не задано, то никакого `WHERE` вообще не будет и вернутся все данные.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас используется Spring Data, то можно использовать `JpaSpecificationExecutor` и написать свою типизированную спецификацию для поиска, или `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` с [QueryDSL](http://querydsl.com/), чтобы написать предикат.  См. [Filtering database rows with spring-data-jpa and spring-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280708/)

Также можно написать SQL-запрос, в котором параметры могут пропускаться путем сравнения с `null`:

```java
@Query("""
       select ye from YourEntity ye where
       (?1 is null or ye.user_type = ?1)
       and (?2 is null or ye.document_type = ?2)
       """)
List<YourEntity> findFiltered(String userType, String documentType);
```